# How to apply function to nested list of String in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I have parsed data from table (by tagSoup) and now i have nested list of data

```
datatable with type [[String]]
```

Now i want to save this data as list of objects [Obj] - lines of table. Each line consist of 5 Strings.

```
data Obj = Obj { pdDate :: String,
    pdTournamentId :: String,
    pdTournamentName :: String,
    pdOperation :: String,
    pdTown :: String }
    deriving (Eq,Show,Read)
```

And I have a function to create the Obj

```
buildObj [a:b:c:d:e] = do
    let lst = last e
    let line = Obj {pdDate = a,
    pdTournamentId = b,
    pdTournamentName = c,
    pdOperation  = d,
    pdTown  = lst}
    return line
```

To pass through the nested list in the main block, I call the function `map`

```
    map buildObj datatable
```

1. And how to save all the data Obj to list [Obj]?

I am very new in Haskell, so looking if anybody could give me pointers to it.

Thanks!

UPDATE: The answer of @Mark Seemann helped to fix error type [[[String]]]

current errors

```
 * Couldn't match expected type `Obj' with actual type `m0 Obj'
    * In a stmt of a 'do' block: return line
```

and

```
 * Couldn't match type `[]' with `IO'
      Expected type: IO Obj
        Actual type: [Obj]
    * In a stmt of a 'do' block: map buildObj datatable
```

Comment: What do you expect `[a:b:c:d:e]` to match?

Comment: @Rein Henrichs 
i expect that there will 5 Strings, i just don't know another way to do this

Comment: So if datatable type  [[String]], i expect that [a:b:c:d:e] - [String] one line of my initial table

Comment: Show the code that generates the error.

Comment: @chepner I updated the question description. I would be grateful for any tips!

Comment: You can't just call `map` in the `do` block, as `map` returns a list, not an `IO` action. You want something like `print $ map buildObj datatable`.

Comment: @chepner do you mean `map buildObj datatable` returns a list [Obj] in my case?
and thanks! this fixed the second error)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The pattern `a:b:c:d:e` matches a *list* with the *head* `a` and *tail* `b:c:d:e`.

The pattern `b:c:d:e`, likewise, would match a list with the *head* `b` and *tail* `c:d:e`.

Reducing further, the pattern `d:e` would match a list with the *head* `d` and the the *tail* `e`.

Thus, `e` is itself a list.

If you want to match on a list with exactly five elements, you can write it as

```
a:b:c:d:e:[]
```

or, alternatively

```
[a,b,c,d,e]
```

Notice that this is an incomplete pattern match. You should also consider what to do if the list is smaller or larger than exactly five elements.

Comment: Thank you! It helped me a lot!
Maybe you can give a hint on this question: how to save all the data Obj to list [Obj] after calling  map buildObj datatable